# Annotation Validation not working for fields that are created in a FOREACH Loop

Tags: html, validation, asp.net-core, foreach, data-annotations

The Annotation Attributes `required` is used for example. It is working for fields i generated manually but not for fields that are created in a FOREACH Loop. The HTML Source Code is exactly the same.

First i tried to just use the tags on the properties. This way the `required` wouldnt produce what it should:

```
data-val="true" data-val-required="Das Feld "weight" ist erforderlich." id="component_weight" name="component.weight" />
```

So i then tried to manually put that code in the FOREACH Loop so it would be applied to the HTML.
It is still not working.

[Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WgEW.png) - It works for the first two but it should work for weight p.e. too

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcZay.png) - The first two are created manually and in weight the dat-validation is 
            created in FOREACH

I thought it might be a ModelBinding Problem but i have no clue really.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: it is pretty complex, the main problem is that i don´t know where the difference is between manually creating it and creating it in a foreach loop

Comment: ` It is working for fields i generated manually but not for fields that are created in a FOREACH Loop` What's your model code and the code of `.cshtml` ?